# How to use EXISTS in BigQuery and acquire what matches the past log

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know. Has anyone who accessed today accessed in the past? The number of people.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(user_id) AS repeater_user_count
FROM
  [access_log] AS table1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-02-28')
AND
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      [access_log] AS table2
    WHERE
      _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-01-31') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-02-27')
    AND
      table1.user_id = table2.user_id
  )
```

However, the BigQuery UI issues an error.

```
Error: error at: 8.1 - 13.184. Only one query can be executed at a time.
```

How can I refer to the same table by BigQuery?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) first. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(user_id) AS repeater_user_count
FROM
  `access_log` AS table1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = '2017-02-28'
AND
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      `access_log` AS table2
    WHERE
      _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND '2017-02-27'
    AND
      table1.user_id = table2.user_id
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS repeater_user_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
  FROM `access_log` 
  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = '2017-02-28'
  )
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
  FROM `access_log` 
  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND '2017-02-27'
  )
```

Comment: @YamadaJP - it's less about standard - it is more about logic of using IN vs EXISTS and even more important  - using DISTINCT which makes query more efficient and btw otherwise your counts are wrong :o)